# DBeaver - Tracking external queries

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm working on application connected to PostgreSQL database. I am wandering is it possible to see sql queries executed from this application by DBeaver or maybe you know other tools to monitor PostgreSQl activity?

Comment: This [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) article answers your question. [log_statement ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-STATEMENT)

Comment: I was hoping it's possible without PgAdmin.

Comment: Yes it is. Dig deeper and edit the log section of file `postgresql.conf`. Don't forget to bring it to its original form once that monitoring is no longer needed.

Comment: Why do you even mention pgAdmin? I think most PostgreSQL users don't use that tool, just another of many available tools. You can even write your own SQL statements for monitoring and display the results in your own application.